# Proving continuity on Sobolev space with weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, sobolev-spaces

Hi I am interested in proving that an operator $$\eta : W^{1,p}(\Omega) \times L^{p}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^{p'}(\Omega)$$ is (weak $\times$ norm, norm) continuous. I want to know if it is viable to try to show the continuity by proving that whenever sequences $x_{n} \rightharpoonup x$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $y_{n} \rightarrow y$ in $L^{p}(\Omega)$ it follows that $\eta(x_{n},y_{n}) \rightarrow \eta(x,y)$ in $L^{p'}(\Omega)$?

I know this is possible if we are trying to prove continuity of a function defined on a domain which is first-countable. I'm not sure if Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with the weak topology is first-countable or if this proof is still possible without it being first-countable?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not enough. Every weakly convergent sequence is bounded, but there are unbounded weakly convergent nets, and the continuity on them does not follow from sequential continuity. However, are you sure that sequential continuity is not enough for your purposes? I find it quite sufficient when working with Sobolev spaces.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Why do you find it sufficient when working with Sobolev spaces? I can't find a result which justifies the use of sequential continuity to imply continuity since one topological space of the product is endowed with the weak topology.

Comment: Sequential continuity does not imply continuity. My point was: whatever you are trying to achieve by using continuity may be doable with sequential continuity.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Oh yeah, but in this case I'm trying to prove continuity.